# Editing a pdf file Android Studio

Tags: android, pdf

I'm doing a project and need some advise on whether it is possible to edit a pdf file in Android Studio.

In the project I'm required to create a template in any text editor (pdf preferably), then edit the template by inserting user information, such as name, address etc..

1. is it possible? If so, please provide some direction.
2. any alternatives? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommended that this question should be moved to SuperUser. This is a tools question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would Google java open source pdf writers. I did this stuff years ago in Java j2ee, can bring in required libraries and do it in android. I don't have a recommended one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will get back to you if I reach a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is for writing android code, not modifying PDFs. Wouldn't make sense to have such a feature in Android Studio.

You should look for alternative tools to handle this condition.

Comment: I understand it is for android code, but how can I produce the required functionality? The app is suppose to edit a template with user information provided by the user, I have been thinking about alternatives but have reached a road block. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So.. you're asking about Android code to modify PDFs? Or what exactly are you trying to get at? please clarify what you are trying to do. You should google about libraries available for pdf writing as it is a standard and has been around quite a while.

Comment: I think I was pretty clear, you're just being a douche bag, sorry to say, I'm not going to tolerate your BS. All you had to say was, yes, you can use java libraries to accomplish the task, and there are many available as mentioned by James Wyman.

Comment: Sorry, I was was not trying to be a douche..merely was just going by what you said, it sounded like you were asking for a Plug-in to Android Studio to modify PDFs... that exactly what you wrote, please be a little clearer and don't assume so much.